# Can haproxy run under supervise when daemon mode is on?

Tags: haproxy, daemontools

We've got haproxy running in non-daemon mode, with DJB's supervise (a.k.a. daemontools) script keeping an eye on it.

However, as our site traffic has grown, its single thread has reached 100% CPU. We'd like to start using haproxy's nbproc option, to get it using multiple cores. However, this requires haproxy to be in "daemon mode".

Is there a way to make haproxy work under supervise while its daemon mode is on? If so, will it properly respond to "svc -d" commands?

And if there is no way, have you guys found it to be reliable enough that we won't *need* supervise anymore?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tested this, I believe you can using the [`fghack`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/fghack.html) program. I'd be curious to know your results or what the eventual solution to this problem was.